# Can Firefox 57+ WebExtensions manipulate userChrome.css?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon-webextensions, userchrome.css

is it possible for a Firefox WebExtension to read/write to a user's userChrome.css file? I was in the process of writing an extension that allows users to customize certain browser icons. I realize this isn't possible without my extension having access to the userChrome.css file. Could reading/writing files be possible through native messaging perhaps?

Comment: No, but they can use `nativeMessaging` API to launch an external utility that can do it.

Comment: @wOxxOm creating an external utility for users to additionally install seems cumbersome for the simple css manipulation Im trying to do. But if this is my only option, I suppose it can't be helped. Thanks for the input.